# Sentry2 user model extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Sentry2 package in my laravel 4 application (http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/).

I create a new User model that extends Sentry2 User Model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

when I execute the follow code I have a exception.

```
$adminUser = User::create(array(
    'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password'    => "admin",
    'first_name'  => 'Admin',
    'last_name'   => 'Admin',
    'activated'   => 1,
));
```

**Error:**

```
 [RuntimeException]
 A hasher has not been provided for the user.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to update the config file of sentry package:

```
'users' => array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "eloquent" driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent models should be used throughout Sentry.
    |
    */

    'model' => '\App\Models\User',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Attribute
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you're the "eloquent" driver and extending the base Eloquent model,
    | we allow you to globally override the login attribute without even
    | subclassing the model, simply by specifying the attribute below.
    |
    */

    'login_attribute' => 'email',

),
```

and use `Sentry::getUserProvider()->create()` method

```
    $adminUser = Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(
        array(
            'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password'    => "admin",
            'first_name'  => 'Admin',
            'last_name'   => 'Admin',
            'activated'   => 1,
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create your object from Eloquent mass alignment you can add the Hasher manually Like that :

```
$user->setHasher(new Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\NativeHasher);
```

Or to be permanent you can add a "boot" method to your User object like this :

```
class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    // ...

    public static function boot()
    {
        self::$hasher = new Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\NativeHasher;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what it tell you is you have to hash and salt your password
so

```
$adminUser = User::create(array(
    'email'       => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password'    => Hash::make('admin'),
    'first_name'  => 'Admin',
    'last_name'   => 'Admin',
    'activated'   => 1,
```

));

Answer (score 0):

I extended the Sentry User Model like you and the same error is returned, then i find an idea in https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/163 and then tried passing a new instance of NativeHasher; i'm not sure if this is the correct way, but in the first test the user was saved correctly:

```
$user = new User;
$user->setHasher(new Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\NativeHasher);
$user->first_name = "Name";
$user->last_name = "Last";
$user->password = 'admin';
$user->email = "email@gmail.com";
$user->save();
```

Comment: Yes you are rigth its ok with Sentry::getUserProvider()->create...., i used this in my repository. thanks